# last modified with grep

Tags: files, grep

I'd like to make a list to stdout of the files modified in the last two hours in the . directory using grep. It has to be automatic (can't ask user what time is it or similar stuff) and I have to use only grep, not conditional statements. This is what I've done by now:

```
#!/bin/bash

#redirect output to a file otherwise grep will read all as one line not giving a readable   output
ls -lrt > ls_out
date > date_extr

# extract hour from date. E interpret what follows as an extended regex. o print only what is matched. m 1 stop after one match
#I'll go back 2 hours
time_=$(date | grep -Eo [0-9]+?: | grep -Eom 1 [0-9]+?)
time_1=$[$time_-1]
time_2=$[$time_-2]

#grep day and month from the previous file "" to include spaces in date_
date_=$(grep -oE [0-9]+\ [A-Za-z]+\  date_extr)
grep "$date_" ls_out > ls_date

#match time as it is if it has 2 digits for example 11, 19, 21. \ number avoid matches as 19: if time_ is 9:
grep \ $time_:      ls_date
grep \ $time_1:     ls_date
grep \ $time_2:     ls_date

#match 09: if time_ output was 9:
grep 0$time_:      ls_date
grep 0$time_1:     ls_date
grep 0$time_2:     ls_date

#cleaning up
rm ls_out ls_date date_extr
```

It works fine, the only problem is that it doesn't list files modified the day before if the script is run at 00 or 1 a.m.

The problem is that ii should grep the date AND the output of ls -lrt and I seem to need an if.

In case you are asking the reason of this question, it is the link where I take it with some modifications:
http://tldp.org/LDP/Bash-Beginners-Guide/html/sect_04_05.html. 
Question number 7.

Comment: Why do you want to use grep for this? It is not the right tool at all.

Comment: `find` is the right tool for this. Using `grep` is simply _wrong_.

Comment: My take on this is that this is simply a bad question. Skip it. I suppose the intent is to make you parse the output of `ls -l`, which is [a bad idea](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs) in the first place, and even if you're doing that `grep` is the wrong tool: it can work, but extracting the date and doing a numerical comparison would be a lot easier.

Answer (score 3):

Use `find . -maxdepth 1 -mmin -120`. If you absolutely must use `grep` you can grep for an empty string: `grep -l '' $(find . -maxdepth 1 -mmin -120)`